# What is torsional strain?

Tags: organic-chemistry, conformers

*I am having difficulty in understanding the concept of torsional strain. Can someone explain it to me in a more elaborate manner?*

I mean why should bond restrict movement in eclipsed conformation? Doesn't that make it unstable! I tried this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strain_%28chemistry%29#Torsional_strain) but I'm still having difficulty in understanding the concept.

Answer (score 2):

For the case of a single bond, consider a simple case like ethane, which can take an eclipsed conformation, a staggered conformation, or anything in between depending on the torsion angle of the C-C bond.  Each carbon has a region of especially high electron density where it's bonded to a hydrogen.  When the torsion angle is changed from staggered to eclipsed, these regions approach eachother and repel, and thus the eclipsed conformation is higher in energy than the staggered.

In the case of a double bond, as in ethylene, the energy associated with torsional strain is much higher because the P orbitals involved in the pi bond have to be oriented the same way.  Thus, applying torsional strain involves breaking this pi bond, and has a high energy.

Comment: Well, you don't have to break the $\pi$ bond to apply torsional strain. Consider biphenyl, where the lowest-energy dihedral angle is *definitely* not flat. I'd consider some torsional strain. There are even "torsional balance" molecules designed to measure this.

Comment: How energy is increased if nothing adds energy to the molecule? Also when in chemistry we speak about energy what is this energy? Potential or kinetic or both?